# Use of static and global variable

Tags: c, variables, static, global

I was going through `global` and `static` variables.I have a question.
If I have a `.c` file and it is having only one user defined `function(ABC())`. Suppose I have to preserve the value of a variable in that function. Should I make that variable `static`(locally in that function) or make it `global`. Which one is best way and why.

Comment: For your question, it just doesn't matter as you question is too hypothetical. The decision should be based on what is the use of the variable and whether you want it to be accessed outside of that function or not.

Answer (score 2):

Rule of thumb: Define variables/functions in the smallest scope possible while avoiding redundant code and data.

I recommend making the variable a `static` variable defined in the scope of the function.